# Custom PowerBI Data Connector Crypto.CreateHash Won't Accept SHA1

Tags: powerquery, m, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to create a custom data connector for PowerBI. I need to create an SHA1 hash for an authentication process. Here is the code that I am currently using

```
let
        nonce = Text.NewGuid(), 
        timestamp = DateTimeZone.ToText(DateTimeZone.UtcNow()),
        digestBin = Crypto.CreateHash(CryptoAlgorithm.SHA1, Text.ToBinary(nonce&timestamp&Extension.CurrentCredential()[Password])),
        digest = Binary.ToText(digestBin, BinaryEncoding.Base64),
        val = "UsernameToken Username=""" & Extension.CurrentCredential()[Username] & """, PasswordDigest=""" & digest & """, Nonce=""" & nonce & """, Created=""" & timestamp & """"
    in
        val;
```

I am getting this error in the query output, "Invalid encryption algorithm".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

CryptoAlgorithm.SHA1 as a hash isn't supported because the SHA-1 hash function is insecure. You can create an HMAC that uses SHA-1 with Crypto.CreateHmac, which some OAuth 1 sources need. You do need a key for this, however.